# Jquery calcutate width issue while first time load

Tags: jquery, width, banner

Images is appearing cumulatively added when page first time load.Jquery not calculate width dynamically but normal appearing second load or after page refresh.What could be the reason?

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
    var imageWidth, totalWidth, sliderContent, $slider;
    $slider = $("#slider");
    sliderContent = $slider.html();
    $slider.html("<div id=\"slideWrapper\">" + sliderContent + "</div>");
    imageWidth = $slider.find("img").width();
    totalWidth = $slider.find("img").size() * imageWidth;
    $("#slider").css("width", imageWidth);
    $("#slideWrapper").css("width", totalWidth);

    $(".next-arr").click(function () {
        if (parseInt($("#slideWrapper").css("margin-left")) < 0 && !$("#slideWrapper").is(":animated")) {
            $("#slideWrapper").stop(true, true).animate({ marginLeft: "+=" + imageWidth + "px" }, 1600);
        }
    });

    $(".prev-arr").click(function () {
        if ((parseInt($("#slideWrapper").css("margin-left")) * -1) < (totalWidth - imageWidth) && !$("#slideWrapper").is(":animated")) {
            $("#slideWrapper").stop(true, true).animate({ marginLeft: "-=" + imageWidth + "px" }, 1600);
        }
    });
});
```

Html:

```
<div id="slider">
    <a href="#" title="img">
        <img src="img.jpg" alt="img" /></a>
    <a href="#" title="img">
        <img src="img.jpg" alt="img" /></a>
    <a href="#" title="img">
        <img src="img.jpg" alt="img" /></a>
    <a href="#" title="img">
        <img src="img.jpg" alt="img" /></a>
</div>
```

Css:

```
#slider {
    overflow: hidden;
}

    #slider a, #slider img {
        float: left;
        overflow: auto;
        position: relative;
    }

    #slideWrapper {
        overflow: hidden;
    }

        #slideWrapper img {
            float: left;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

other way you can use `$(window).load` ,may be your function executes before the load of images therefore for second time images are appearing from cache so they would not take time on first load images are not appearing from cache.

```
$(window).load(function(){
var imageWidth, totalWidth, sliderContent, $slider;
$slider = $("#slider");
sliderContent = $slider.html();
$slider.html("<div id=\"slideWrapper\">" + sliderContent + "</div>");
imageWidth = $slider.find("img").width();
totalWidth = $slider.find("img").size() * imageWidth;
$("#slider").css("width", imageWidth);
$("#slideWrapper").css("width", totalWidth);
// other code .....
});
```

hope this makes sense

Comment: Thanks for your response.But $(window).load() function very slowly.The  problem is continue.

Comment: i have clearly mentioned on first load your images will load as fresh image and then browser caches it therefore second time they will be fetched from the cache and loads quickly

Comment: i encounter this problem when i open html with Chrome and Safari

Comment: other way you can use the `jquery image load event` http://api.jquery.com/load-event/ see this

Comment: i check with console.log(), imageWidth and totalWidth values are 0.